# Azure / Videoindexer AI API / Visual Recognition Classes list

Tags: azure, classification, azure-video-indexer

Is it possible to retrieve the full list of default recognized classes of Azure Video Indexer?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Video Analyzer for Media, a.k.a. Video Indexer, supports thousands of class labels for video frames classification referred to as *Labels*. Although the full list is not available online you can easily infer the classes relevant for your data with a few API calls... Feel free to reach out the customer support at: visupport@microsoft.com for additional assistance.